# I have converted a continuous feature to categorical. I am getting NaN in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have converted a continuous dataset to categorical. I am getting nan values when ever the value of the continuous data is 0.0 after conversion. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
df = pd.read_csv('NSL-KDD/KDDTrain+.txt',header=None)
data = df[33]
bins = [0.000,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00]
category = pd.cut(data,bins)
category = category.to_frame()
print (category)
```

How do I convert the values so that I dont get NaN values.  I have attached two screenshots for better understanding how the actual data looks and how the convert data looks. [This is the main dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMbDB.png). [This is the what it becomes after using bins and pandas.cut()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biF0e.png). How can thos "0.00" stays like the other values in the dataset.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot.  Also, without sample data from `NSL-KDD/KDDTrain+.txt`, it's difficult to reproduce the error.

Comment: add fillna(0)??

Comment: your bins can be written as `bins = np.arange(0,1.05,0.05)`.

Comment: fillna is not not working I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `pd.cut`, you can specify the parameter `include_lowest = True`. This will make the first internal left inclusive (it will include the 0 value as your first interval starts with 0).

So in your case, you can adjust your code to be

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
df = pd.read_csv('NSL-KDD/KDDTrain+.txt',header=None)
data = df[33]
bins = [0.000,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30,0.35,0.40,0.45,0.50,0.55,0.60,0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,1.00]
category = pd.cut(data,bins,include_lowest=True)
category = category.to_frame()
print (category)
```

Documentation Reference for [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Comment: I will surely try this but what I have done is include -1.0 in the bins and it worked. I just extended the least value

Comment: Yep, that should work. If you use the `include_lowest=True`, you will have `(-0.001, 0.05]` instead of `NaN`. It basically automatically extends the least value for you.

Comment: If this worked and was helpful, please consider marking it as the correct answer :) @user6565467

Comment: Yes thanks for you help. And the least value is automatically included and it doesnt show any NaN